# Can I have only grandchild classes implement a method in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

This is my class diagram:

[image]

Here is the parent class:

```
class Non_Player_Character
{
public:
    virtual void update(World & world, map<string, shared_ptr<Character>> & actors) = 0;

protected:
    Non_Player_Character(const string & name, const string & faction_ID, const string & set_ai_type) { }
};
```

One of the child classes:

```
class Hostile_NPC : public Non_Player_Character
{
protected:
    Hostile_NPC(const string & name, const string & faction_ID, const string & ai_type) : Non_Player_Character(name, faction_ID, ai_type) {}
};
```

One of the grandchild classes:

```
class Hostile_NPC_Fighter : public Hostile_NPC
{
public:
    Hostile_NPC_Fighter(const string & name, const string & faction_ID) :
        Hostile_NPC(name, faction_ID, C::AI_TYPE_FIGHTER) {}

    void update(World & world, map<string, shared_ptr<Character>> & actors);
};
```

Implementing each grandchild's `update()` method and compiling yields this:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(1172): error C2259: 'Hostile_NPC' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Non_Player_Character::update(World &,std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Character>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &)' : is abstract
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Character>
1>          ]
1>          ...\non_player_character.h(22) : see declaration of 'Non_Player_Character::update'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(1185) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Get_align<Hostile_NPC>' being compiled
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\memory(953) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::alignment_of<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Hostile_NPC
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\memory(1003) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Hostile_NPC
1>          ]
1>          game.cpp(30) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<Hostile_NPC> std::make_shared<Hostile_NPC,Hostile_NPC_Fighter&>(Hostile_NPC_Fighter &)' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\type_traits(1174): error C2259: 'Hostile_NPC' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Non_Player_Character::update(World &,std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Character>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &)' : is abstract
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Character>
1>          ]
1>          ...\non_player_character.h(22) : see declaration of 'Non_Player_Character::update'
```

(The parent class here does have a parent class of its own, but I didn't include it as it doesn't have an `update()` method)

Both child classes and the parent class have protected constructors so that only the grandchild classes can be instantiated. I want every grandchild class to implement its own `update()` method.

The idea is to have a map of type `<string, Non_Player_Character>` and populate it with grandchild objects. An iterator calls `.update(arg1, arg2)` on each one.

1. How do I make this work?
2. Can I do this without putting anything `update()`-related in the child classes, only in the parent and grandchild classes?
3. Can I enforce implementation of `update()` for all grandchildren?

Also, am I using public/protected appropriately?

Comment: Please post a [complete, minimal and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I have tried to put your snippets together and if I add what I think are obvious omissions, it compiles fine.  In its current form, I cannot diagnose your problem.

Comment: It would be better if you did it not in the future but right now. Questions on SO are supposed to help everyone, so the quality of this post — even if, or _especially_ if, you have already solved your problem for you — is still relevant and up for improvement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want the grandchildren to implement `update()`, then why not put your `virtual void` in `Hostile_NPC`?

*Maybe I missunderstood your concept here, so:*

The other attempt in OOP is to use interfaces, something like "UpdateableCharacter" that you derive from within classes that should implement this method.

Comment: Primarily because both `Hostile_NPC` and `Neutral_NPC` have child classes (only two shown), and I only want to have `update()` declared in one place. Regarding interfaces, if I declare `update()` in an `UpdateableCharacter` class, will the compiler still allow me to call `update()` on the contents of the map?

Comment: Then why not declare it in `Hostile_NPC`? Then `Neutral_NPC` won't have the `update()` method.

Comment: `Neutral_NPC` also needs to have the `update()` method for its children (mentioned but not shown).

Comment: Then you should declare `update()` in the `Non_Player_Character` class, right?

Comment: That's what I have above.

Comment: I get it. You don't want the update method in the class inbetween. Why not declare it with `void update() = 0`, so it is "undeclared"?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed one issue. The other issue was me.

Comment: Could you accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this solves anything. Re-declaring an inherited pure virtual function as pure is not necessary.